# WSL-2 Ubuntu 20.04 JavaFX error while using Java 8

Tags: java, javafx, ubuntu-20.04, wsl-2

I am using WSL-2 Ubuntu 20.04 on windows10 and I want to run a java application on it but I get the following error:

> Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run
> this application

It is strange because I have installed Java 8 which has JavaFX included.
`java -version` gives me back the following:

```
java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_312"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_312-8u312-b07-0ubuntu1~20.04-b07)OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.312-b07, mixed mode)

javac -version
javac 1.8.0_312
```

I am running the java program in the following way:
`java -jar myprogram.jar`

What do I miss?

Comment: JavaFX is not part of OpenJDK 8 (it was only ever a part of Oracle JDK). Use a more recent JDK and OpenJFX, following the documentation at https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/

Comment: Also, JavaFX requires graphical screen access, so it might be better to run your application directly from Windows, than trying to run it from WSL (I'm not sure if WSL already supports graphical screen access or not).